# UIView shadow not showing in iphone 5s

Tags: swift, uiview, shadow, dropshadow

I have a UIView and want to add shadow to it. So I get a code given below, which is working good in all iphone simulators and devices, but doesn't show shadow in iphone 5s and simulator as well.

```
class ShadowView: UIView {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            setupShadow()
        }
    }

    private func setupShadow() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)).cgPath
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the iOS for the iPhone5s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you!!

```
import UIKit

class ShadowView: UIView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Jadhav, Its working Fine, Mine was not working UITableViewCell.

Comment: I'm glad!! If you like it please upward the answer ;)